# Activity or fragment or dialog

Tags: android, android-activity

Hello I am looking for a solution to my app. I have 10 Buttons on my second activity. Now what I want is a screen to come up once any of the Buttons are pressed with information. (just text) I have been looking for some time now and I don't know which one is the best. I don't think Activities are the best bet because I don't want it to be activity heavy being slow and all.

Hope you can help thanks

Comment: You should check out Fragments, since Fragments are light-weight components and also they make your application look more dynamic and professional...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for a custom dialog ?

[Tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/)

Comment: Thanks will look into this but just reading about fragments which sounds very good thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this to show a dialog.

```
private void ShowDialog(String message){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder;
    AlertDialog alert;

    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    builder.setMessage(message)                 
           .setCancelable(false)
           .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.button_ok), new       DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
               }
           });
    alert = builder.create();

    alert.show();
}
```

On your button click just call with some info...

```
 ShowDialog("Some Information.");
```